# How to keep corner radius of a button when it is enlarged by Anima

Tags: sketch-app

I use Sketch along with the Anima Toolkit to control the padding of buttons, here is a button I created for the small screen:

[image]

When I increase the button text size, the button is enlarged thanks to the Anima Toolkit, but it also changes the corner radius, which is undesired:

[image]

How can I keep the corner radius?

Comment: In fact it *is* keeping the corner radius the same, whilst the rectangle to which its applied is scaling - I've not used the Anima Toolkit - is there perhaps a toggle somewhere for "scale all" or some equivalent?